# about a proof of baire“s theorem of rudin's' functional analysis in p.43

Tags: general-topology

$S$ is a topogical space, $U$ is an open set that is dense, $A$ is a open set .Can we find a open set which  it's closure is contained in $U \cap A$?

Comment: (1). "Is contained in" does not mean "is a proper subset of". Any set is contained in itself. (2). The empty set is open and is it own closure and is contained in every set.

Comment: I think what you are thinking of is: If $U$ is dense open and $A$ is non-empty open does there exist non-empty open $B$ with $\overline B\subset A\cap U$? This is not always true, but it is  true for metric spaces. But the Baire Category Theorem does not apply to all spaces.   Spaces which satisfy it are called Baire spaces. Completely metrizable spaces are  Baire spaces. E.g.$ \Bbb Q $ is not a Baire space but $\Bbb R$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is a regular (!) topological space, $U$ is open dense and $A$ is non-empty open, then
$U \cap A \neq \emptyset$ as $U$ is dense, so pick $p$ in this intersection.

Also $U \cap A$ is open in $S$ as both sets are open. Then $p \in U \cap A$ and regularity of $S$ implies that there is an open set $B$ with $p \in B \subseteq \overline{B} \subseteq U \cap A$.

In Rudin this step is applied to metric spaces, IIRC, and these are certainly regular (and more).